getting error while deploying ethereum smart contract using truffle
my code for migration is
type here
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract UserRegistry {
    mapping(address => bool) public registeredUsers;

    event UserRegistered(address indexed user);

    function registerUser() public {
        require(!registeredUsers[msg.sender], "User already registered");
        registeredUsers[msg.sender] = true;
        emit UserRegistered(msg.sender);
    }

    function isUserRegistered(address user) public view returns (bool) {
        return registeredUsers[user];
    }
}


but when i try command npx truffle migrate --network development i am getting error
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:
Error: Cannot find module '../binaries/uws_win32_x64_120.node'
Require stack:

C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\ganache\node_modules@trufflesuite\uws-js-unofficial\src\uws.js
C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\ganache\dist\node\core.js
C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\truffle\build\migrate.bundled.js
C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\original-require\index.js
C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.

Compiling your contracts...

Compiling .\contracts\UserRegistry.sol
Compiling .\contracts\UserRegistry.sol
Compilation warnings encountered:

Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

--> project:/contracts/UserRegistry.sol

Artifacts written to C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\build\contracts
Compiled successfully using:


solc: 0.8.21+commit.d9974bed.Emscripten.clang

Starting migrations...

Network name:    'development'
Network id:      5777
Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

2_deploy_contracts.js
Replacing 'UserRegistry'
*** Deployment Failed ***
"UserRegistry" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
"UserRegistry" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

at C:\Users\Tushar\peer-tutoring-network\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1

Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Node v21.7.0
I am expesting the contract to run
